# Is there such a thing as a software internet radio where I can add the stations I want to listen to?

Tags: internet-radio

Is there such a thing as a software internet radio where I can add the stations I want to listen to?
Open source would be great.

Thanks

EDIT: by "adding stations" I mean being able to listen to the CBC here in Canada, for example.

Comment: Yes, you can not only listen to CBC, but it's got in in the presets already (a whole bunch of them actually). You can also put any station in the favorites yourself. Try it, small, portable, ... my main source of radio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean about adding stations. Is [Screamer Radio](http://www.screamer-radio.com/) what you're looking for? Freeware (and 'portable'), unfortunately not open source.

[image]

[image]

Comment: +1 i can confirm that Screamer has already a dozen "CBC" radio stations from Canada in its "Presets".

Comment: Oh, hey, thanks Molly. I told him already up in the comments, but a screenshot always gives that extra credibility :)

Comment: With Screamer you have a winner ... it's the finest. :)

Comment: @ldigas - You're comment above doesn't tell us the name of the app you were thinking of...

Comment: @Joe Internet - what are you speaking of ? I fail to understand.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of radio stations stream their audio on their websites. Like CBC, for example: http://www.cbc.ca/radio/

Comment: Thanks. I know this, but I want something simpler than opening separate windows for each station.

Answer (score 0):

I listen my favorite radio station right in the browser in Google Chrome with [Chrome-Radio](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/hgjdhckebbdoobhniheihpdogeoeelbn). You can add station and create favorite list and lots more things. Try it! It is really cool.